# material UI modal not blurring nor darkening background

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material UI modal and it is not blurring nor darkening background and background is open to click
everything behind the modal is clickable and by clicking outside its not even closing modal

```js
    <Modal
      hideBackdrop={false}
      disableAutoFocus
      disableEnforceFocus
      open={open}
      onClose={() => handleClose()}
      sx={{     
        top: "50%",
        left: "50%",
        transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
        width: "75vw",
        height: "85.5vh",
        color: "white",
        bgcolor: "black",
        boxShadow: 24,
        backdropFilter: "blur(5px)",
        border: "10px solid black",
        borderRadius: 4,
      }}
      aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
      aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
    >
     {children}
   </Modal>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem could come from the properties `disableAutoFocus` or `disableEnforceFocus`. Do you actually need them? The documentation recommends to never set them to `true`. [Modal API - Material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/modal/)